# DD_belatedPNG without editing the markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, png, transparency

I'd like to use [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) for a project, but I'm not allowed to edit the markup to add the following conditional comment that is required for the script to function:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script src="DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
<script>
  /* EXAMPLE */
  DD_belatedPNG.fix('.png_bg');

  /* string argument can be any CSS selector */
  /* .png_bg example is unnecessary */
  /* change it to what suits you! */
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I'm already using jQuery on this project and I can also detect IE, so I wonder if its possible to place the `DD_belatedPNG.fix();` function inside my `$(document).ready()`? Would it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check [`jQuery.browser`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser), like so:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)
        $.getScript ('DD_belatedPNG.js', DD_belatedPNG.fix);
});
```

This will load the external JS file for DD_belatedPNG as well, and call the `fix` method once loaded

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would. Using `$(document).ready()`, or the shortcut `$(function() {}`, has the same effect than adding the conditional comment.